# Comparison of smooth and etale topologies

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'd like to understand that any smooth covering can be refined by an etale covering. There is a proof on the Stacks project (tag [055S](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/055S)) but it doesn't clarify the situation to me. Does anyone have an intuitive explanation of this?